# WAR doesn't get redeployed in Glassfish from autodeploy

Tags: deployment, glassfish-3, autodeploy

I was able to deploy my WAR the first time I placed it under `domains/domain1/autodeploy` dir.  However, after making some changes and redeploying the WAR to the `autodeploy` dir, the changes were not picked up.  I even deleted `domains/domain1/applications/myapp` (where `myapp` corresponds to the `myapp.jar` being deployed) but the WAR was not redeployed.  The server was started and stopped via `asadmin`:

```
asadmin start-domain
asadmin stop-domain
```

What am I doing wrong so that the app does not get redeployed?

**UPDATE:**  I tried manually (re)deploying (also using `--force` option) the WAR but got the following error in `server.log`:

```
[#|2013-03-17T20:47:36.177-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=72;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Application with name myprojectname is already registered. Either specify that redeployment must be forced, or redeploy the application. Or if this is a new deployment, pick a different name|#]
```

I do not know how to unregister/undeploy an app that's been once deployed.  I tried removing all the references to my app in `domain.xml` but it didn't work. This seems like a very basic bug in the software.

Comment: Is there anything in the Glassfish log files that might help?

Answer (score 11):

I know this was answered long ago, but in case anyone else gets here via google like I did, I have another possible answer ...

After encountering this same issue, I found the following ... the autodeploy/.autodeploystatus directory still had a file referencing the application I was trying to redeploy by copying the war into the autodeploy directory.  I had to delete the file in the autodeploy/.autodeploystatus directory, then my application was deployed when the war was copied into the autodeploy directory.

Hope that helps.

NOTE: Apparently, [it is obvious](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20234?focusedCommentId=360753&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-360753) to others who use glassfish that you have to delete all this stuff from the hidden .autodeploystatus directory to get your re-deploys to work.  Why is it obvious to them?  We may never know.

Answer (score 3):

You can undeploy via asadamin with:

```
asadmin undeploy yourapplication
```

You can also visit the glassfish admin console `http://localhost:4848` and undeploy via the graphical interface (look at Applications).

In general the re-autodeployment should work, but I would recommend using the normal deploy method or an incremental redeployment by some IDE like NetBeans...

Comment: I tried what you say but it told me that no such app existed. But when I tried to redeploy it, it told me it existed.  #puzzled

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem reappears for an application running to be deployed in Payara `5.2021.10` (perhaps for other recent versions > `5.193`) within a `docker` container.

The problem happens **every** time the `docker` container restarts - the deployment fails with a message:

> Application with name {applicationName} is already registered. Either
> specify that redeployment must be forced, or redeploy the application.
> Or if this is a new deployment, pick a different name

The problem can be fixed by a forced redeploy. Place something like this into a `Dockerfile` of the application image:

```bash
ENV DEPLOY_PROPS="--force=true"
```

This environment variable allows to set custom parameters to `asadmin`'s `deploy` command. How exactly is it applied can be seen in [the script that generates the deploy commands](https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/blob/master/bin/init_1_generate_deploy_commands.sh#L43), that is being run from within the container's entrypoint.