# Where would i put .war file in glassfish server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, server, glassfish-4

I have started `WebApplication1` from netbeans, now where would i put the .war file in glassfish server?

Here? `/home/shibly/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/__internal`

I see an empty folder named `WebApplication1` in `/home/shibly/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/__internal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try entering

```
http://localhost:4848
```

in your web browser, where you'll enter the GlassFish Administration Console. On the left side do the following Applications --> Deploy --> Select .war file --> OK. Your file is now uploaded!

Comment: After selecting the war file and clicking ok got error `Error occurred during deployment: Application with name WebApplication1 is already registered. Either specify that redeployment must be forced, or redeploy the application. Or if this is a new deployment, pick a different name. Please see server.log for more details.`

Comment: Try undeploying the file first under application (if there is a file there) otherwise check out these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467756/war-doesnt-get-redeployed-in-glassfish-from-autodeploy, they cover it pretty well!

Comment: Where does netbean put .war file in glassfish during run?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the [autodeploy](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/821-0186/geyvj/index.html) folder?

If you copy the war to `/domains/domain1/autodeploy/` then glassfish will attempt to deploy it automatically.